# How to describe the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices of rank $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, matrix-rank

This problem came with a statement which I already proved.

> $M(n;\mathbb{R})$ has a linear subspace $V$ of dimension $n(n-1)$ which consists entirely of singular matrices.

So, I tried to describe the set $B$ which consists entirely of $2 \times 2$ matrices of rank $1$ in terms of dimension and isomorphisms with the statement above.

> Let the set $A = \{ M \in M(2,\mathbb{R}) | \det(M)=0 \}$.
>
> Then, by the statement, $\dim(A)=2$.
>
> But, note that every $2 \times 2$ matrices that have rank of $1$ are in the form $$\begin{bmatrix}
> a & ka \\
> b & kb \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$, and "$a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$."
>
> Then, we can see that the determinants of such matrices are always $0$.
>
> Now, let the set $B$ be the set of all such matrices.
>
> Clearly, $B \subset A$.
>
> As we want to show that $B$ is a space in $A$, we can apply the subspace test to $B$.
>
> Let $m_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
> a & k_1a \\
> b & k_1b \\
> \end{bmatrix}$, and $m_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
> c & k_2a \\
> d & k_2b \\
> \end{bmatrix}$. Then, $m_1 + m_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
> a+c & k_1a+k_2c \\
> b+d & k_1b + k_2d \\
> \end{bmatrix}$.

I had to stop here because the second column of this matrix may not depend on the first column.

Questions:

- How do we show a set is a space? (It is a fundamental question, but I want to clarify the distinction between the space and the subspace.) I also went over the axioms of vector space, but this also does not work for the same reason.
- How should be the statement applied to this problem?
  I.e: Assuming we have a dimension of the set(or space) $B$, what can we say about $B$ in terms of dimension?

**Edit:** Thanks to all of the help, I concluded the set (call it $M$) as

> $M=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{R}}\text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & k \\
> 0 & 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 &0  \\
> 1 &k  \\
> \end{bmatrix} \right\} \setminus \{0\}$, which is an infinite union of subsets of $A$ with each $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

I hope this is the right description of $M$.

Another question:

- However, I'm still wondering if this set still could be categorized as a space.

Comment: The set $A$ is not a subspace, i.e. it's not a vector space under the usual definition of addition and scalar multiplication for $2 \times 2$ matrices. It's possible to redefine the addition and scalar multiplication to something less straightforward so that the set becomes a vector space, but this is not what the question is asking. You don't have to show that **all** non-invertible matrices form a subspace (which they don't), you just need to find a subspace consisting only of non-invertible matrices (hint: think of very simple sufficient conditions to show $\det A = 0$).

Comment: As a proof of concept, consider the subspace$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} : x \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$Note that this is a subspace, and every matrix in this subspace has determinant $0$. It's not quite large enough dimension; see if you can extend it.

Comment: This set is plainly the hypersurface with equation $\det A=ad-bc=0$ in $\mathbb R^4$ with coordinates $(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: It is this hypersurface minus the $0$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Your idea to consider matrices of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & ka\\ b & kb\end{pmatrix}$$ goes in the right direction. If you fix $k$ and let $a,b$ be variable in $\mathbb R$, you then get a dimension $2$ linear subspace. Which can be proven using the subspace axioms.

Even simpler,

$$V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & a\\ b & b\end{pmatrix} \mid (a,b) \in \mathbb R^2\right\}$$ is a linear subspace of $M(2;\mathbb R)$ of dimension equal to $2$ (*can you find a basis*?).

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I can see that $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & k \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & k \\
\end{bmatrix}$ works like a basis of a set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with rank $1$ (call it $M$.) However, I'm still stuck at dealing with $k$ here because when $k$ has a different value, the set would have different subset of $M$. Moreover, since $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ can't be in $M$, my basis actually fails to describe $M$. What else should I consider?

Comment: Or, should I just conclude $M = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{R}}\text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & k \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  \\
1 &k  \\
\end{bmatrix} \right\} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is spanned by $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0& k \\ 1 & k \\ \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ as $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = 0\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0 \\ 1 & k \\ \end{bmatrix}$$.

Comment: @mathcounterexample.net $M$ is the set of all matrices that have rank $1$, so I excluded the $0$ matrix.

Comment: @john OK. Just have in mind then that this subset **is not a linear subspace.**